# Sql Server integration with SalesForce

Tags: integration

Is there any way to perform the CRUD operation on the SalesForce object and fields from SQL Server queries like SSIS, or anything?

Comment: I know about http://forceamp.com/ for one but it's paid. Never used it but my colleague seemed quite happy with it. No idea about free packages, search for "Salesforce.com ODBC connector"? Another thing that comes to mind is informatica on demand but sounds like overkill... Also: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5002/which-free-commercial-salesforce-to-sql-app-should-i-use

Answer (score 4):

The free jitterbit salesforce data loader does that.

You can hook up the source as a SQL database, pick a table, create your query, and then set your target as your salesforce object.  And then you can have it run on a schedule.

I currently have it grabbing data from a oracle11g database and upserting to SF every minute.  Shockingly awesome that it's free.

http://www.jitterbit.com/solutions/salesforce-integration/salesforce-data-loader/

Comment: Not sure if this is the right URL, but it's saying that it's free for a 30 day trial.  Is the URL still pointing to the right place?

Comment: Looks like it may have changed.  Used to be a downloadable thing.  The cloud version is newer.

Answer (score 2):

Informatica power-center or on demand can be used to connect SQL and sfdc.There are other integration tools such as Dell bhoomi or Cast iron with SQL connectors and SFDC connector that can help in data import and export

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Talend](http://www.talend.com/download) for such integration. It is free and there is Salesforce connector available out of the box. It is also great that you can export your integration job to a `.bat` file and schedule it with some tool i.e. Windows Scheduler so that your integration will run at a specified time daily or whenever you need.