# MS-SQL Integration with Salesforce

Tags: apex, webservices, integration

1. What is the best way to implement a Batch process between MS-SQL and Salesforce?
2. How to get the data from MS-SQL to Salesforce using any tool or webservice?

Are there any materials to learn about these topics?

Comment: What do you have on top of the MS-SQL database? If it's a .NET site then maybe this will help - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Bachovski, I need a SQL Server Integration with Salesforce materials..Because I am a newbie for this topic so kindly help on this..

Comment: Your question is too broad, please try to narrow it, add some code samples, what you tried, where you read, etc.. as it stands, it is flagged for closure, please try to edit it, and improve it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of achieving that, it really depends on your requirements and complexity. There is a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12217/sql-server-integration-with-salesforce) asked on this site previously, so hopefully one of the answers will give you a starting point of how you can proceed.

Other tools that you can use apart from JitterBit and Informatica are Pervasive, [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/salesforce/sql-server/) and I guess there are many more, so it's really up to you which one you're going to chose.

Comment: Thanks for your support @Bachovski, Now I get some ideas about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [DBAmp](http://www.forceamp.com/) in the past. It got the job done, but as the integration got more complete over time parts became less ideal.

For future integration projects I went with a .NET service working directly with the Salesforce APIs that could move the data as required. I found this easier to handle the sessions, map the data and handle exceptions that might occur. It was particularly important to consider how many API calls were occurring and how this would scale with the number of records being synced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Informatica Cloud or Bhoomi or a similar Integration service provider. Informatica Cloud worked well for me. 
You can also roll out a custom service written in Java or .NET built on top of Salesforce SOAP API + Bulk API.