# can salesforce integrate to sql server using Jitterbit

Tags: integration, jitterbit

I have never used Jitterbit and was wondering if Jitterbit can be automated to pull opportunity and related opportunity data and pushed into a sql server db?  Is this possible using Jitterbit? I was looking on the Jitterbit website for documentation.

Comment: Yes it is.......

Comment: Thanks Eric...you don't have a link to some documentation by chance?

Comment: @Dman, check out the links below.  You can move data back and forth between your sql server and Salesforce.  I am using web services to do this; however, Jitterbit is a quick and easy solution -- and free!

http://www.jitterbit.com/solutions/salesforce-integration/salesforce-data-loader/

http://www.jitterbit.com/solutions/salesforce-integration/

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12217/sql-server-integration-with-salesforce